# blue box glitch, oscommerce

Tags: php, layout, oscommerce, visual-glitch

The problem is here: 
http://netadvokaten.se/index.php

All of a sudden this blue box has appeared out of nowhere!

I am running the latest version of OsCommerce and after hours of googeling it seams like I am the only one that ever had this problem.

I have no blue image embedded in the code and I have NO idea what to do.

Sincerely.

Comment: Hmmmm its the TARDIS! The Doctor saved us all!!

Answer (score 3):

This is the CSS of your body element, notice anything?

```
body {
   background: #fff url(images/blue.jpg) no-repeat center scroll;
   color: #000;
   margin: 0px;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: How did it get there! :O 
Aliens? 

Thank you anyway. 

2 days of my life I never get back.

Comment: HAHAHAAHAHA MOST EPIC ANSWER ON SO EVER

Comment: @AdrianLarsson again. it was the TARDIS, I am sure of it.

Comment: @Neal nah this is a case of a vampire disease , a rare one known as help vampireism i am sure it was a symptom of some antidote against vampires ^_^